# How do you refer to an object within an object using index positions? Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Say I have some objects like what's shown below. What I want to do is refer to the index positions in myObjects. For example, myObjects[0].parameter1 would be give me blue. However referencing stuff by index positions doesn't seem to work in objects. Am I just getting the syntax wrong or is this just not possible with javascript?

```
let myObjects= {
     objectA:{
         parameter1: blue,
         parameter2: 5,
     },
     object B:{
         parameter1: orange,
         parameter2: 4,
     },
}
```

Comment: nope ... besides the invalid syntax of the provided object literal, `myObjects[0]` tries to access a non existing key, here `'0'`, thus the result of this operation is undefined, which is the reason why `myObjects[0].parameter1` will throw an `'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parameter1')'`

Answer (score -1):

Updated post below

```
let myObjects = [
    {
      parameter1: 'blue',
      parameter2: 5,
    },
    {
      parameter1: 'orange',
      parameter2: 4,
    },
  ]

  let obj = myObjects.find(o => o.parameter1 === 'blue');
  console.log(obj)
```

I also included how you can find that object with a specific parameter, in this case blue and then return it to a variable. Obviously im just console logging the object, but you can use it for whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea I could put objects in an array lol

Comment: @raypenbar no worries

Let us know if you can find it by index or if you need more help.

Comment: @raypenbar you can. but you can't do it like Freddy suggests. He's keying the objects in the array as if it were an object.